# How to use multiple, but a limited number of threads in Python to process a list

Tags: python, multithreading, pandas, arcgis

I have a dataframe, several thousand rows in length, that contains two pairs of GPS coordinates in one of the columns, with which I am trying to calculate the drive time between those coordinates. I have a function that takes in those coordinates and returns the drive time and it takes maybe 3-8 seconds to calculate each entry. So, the total process can take quite a while. What I'd like to be able to do is: using maybe 3-5 threads, iterate through the list and calculate the drive time and move on to the next entry while the other threads are completing and not creating more than 5 threads in the process. Independently, I have everything working - I can run multiple threads, I can track the thread count and wait until the max number of allowed threads drops below limit until the next starts and can iterate the dataframe and calculate the drive time. However, I'm having trouble piecing it all together. Here's an edited, slimmed down version of what I have.

```
import pandas
import threading
import arcgis

class MassFunction:
    #This is intended to keep track of the active threads
    MassFunction.threadCount = 0

    def startThread(functionName,params=None):
        #This kicks off a new thread and should count up to keep track of the threads
        MassFunction.threadCount +=1

        if params is None:
            t = threading.Thread(target=functionName)
        else:
            t = threading.Thread(target=functionName,args=[params])
        t.daemon = True
        t.start()

class GeoAnalysis:
    #This class handles the connection to the ArcGIS services
    def __init__(self):
        super(GeoAnalysis, self).__init__()
        self.my_gis = arcgis.gis.GIS("https://www.arcgis.com", username, pw)

    def drivetimeCalc(self, coordsString):
        #The coords come in as a string, formatted as 'lat_1,long_1,lat_2,long_2'
        #This is the bottleneck of the process, as this calculation/response
        #below takes a few seconds to get a response
        points = coordsString.split(", ")
        route_service_url = self.my_gis.properties.helperServices.route.url
        self.route_layer = arcgis.network.RouteLayer(route_service_url, gis=self.my_gis)
        point_a_to_point_b = "{0}, {1}; {2}, {3}".format(points[1], points[0], points[3], points[2])
        result = self.route_layer.solve(stops=point_a_to_point_b,return_directions=False, return_routes=True,output_lines='esriNAOutputLineNone',return_barriers=False, return_polygon_barriers=False,return_polyline_barriers=False)
        travel_time = result['routes']['features'][0]['attributes']['Total_TravelTime']
        #This is intended to 'remove' one of the active threads 
        MassFunction.threadCount -=1
        return travel_time


class MainFunction:
    #This is to give access to the GeoAnalysis class from this class
    GA = GeoAnalysis()

    def closureDriveTimeCalc(self,coordsList):
        #This is intended to loop in the event that a fifth loop gets started and will prevent additional threads from starting
        while MassFunction.threadCount > 4:
            pass
        MassFunction.startThread(MainFunction.GA.drivetimeCalc,coordsList)

    def driveTimeAnalysis(self,location):
        #This reads a csv file containing a few thousand entries. 
        #Each entry/row contains gps coordinates, which need to be 
        #iterated over to calculate the drivetimes
        locationMemberFile = pandas.read_csv(someFileName)
        #The built-in apply() method in pandas seems to be the
        #fastest way to iterate through the rows

        locationMemberFile['DRIVETIME'] = locationMemberFile['COORDS_COL'].apply(self.closureDriveTimeCalc)
```

When I run this right now, using VS Code, I can see the thread counts go up into the thousands in the call stack, so I feel like it is not waiting for the thread to finish and adding/subtracting from the threadCount value.  Any ideas/suggestions/tips would be much appreciated.

EDIT: Essentially my problem is how do I get the travel_time value back so that it can be placed into the dataframe. I currently have no return statement for closureDriveTimeCalc function, so while the function runs correctly, it doesn't send any information back into the apply() method.

Comment: Are you using CPython? Because your threading is probably going to be thwarted by the GIL since this looks like CPU bound

Comment: I am not doing anything special in those terms. I use either Sublime or VS Code during the testing process and then compile to an exe when things are stable. This example is a small snippet within a much larger program. I'm not sure if that answers your question. If it doesn't I can attempt to clarify.

Comment: OK, nvm, I realized the function that you are passing to the threads are I/O bound, so this will not be affected by the GIL

Answer (score 0):

Rather than do this in an apply, I'd use [multiprocessing Pool.map](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/multiprocessing.html?highlight=process):

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

with Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    locationMemberFile['DRIVETIME'] = pool.map(self.closureDriveTimeCalc, locationMemberFile['COORDS_COL']))
```

Comment: Thanks for the input @Andy Hayden I gave your suggestion a shot but had to make a few modifications. Since I needed the output from the closureDriveTimeCalc function, I modified the code a bit, from which resulted in one problem and arose one concern. This multiprocessing seems to be considerably slower than the multi threading and the return values 'doubled.' So if I looped through 1000 sets of coordinates to calculate a drivetime, it returned 2000 results, where every other value was None. It's very odd and I'm not yet sure why it would do that.

Comment: @NLee23 you can also use `from multiprocessing.pool import ThreadPool` similarly. If task is IO bound rather than CPU bound this may be faster.

Comment: It is IO bound, so perhaps I should try that instead. Thanks for the suggestion!